# Ruby, How I can obtain the whole namespace definition path for a method inside the same method?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

How I can obtain the whole namespace definition path for a method inside the same method?

Using this example to make easy the question:

```
module Parent
    module Child
        def self.get_complete_namespace
            this_path = ???
            puts this_path.to_s
        end
    end
end

Parent::Child.get_complete_namespace
#=> "Parent::Child.get_complete_namespace"
```

So to puts or print out this string "Parent::Child.get_complete_namespace", what is the "this_path" variable value using self super o something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any existing functions for this, though you could pretty easily create one using `__callee__` (or `__method__`)

```rb
module Parent
  module Child
    def self.get_complete_namespace
      m = method(__callee__)
      "#{m.receiver.name}.#{m.name}"
    end
  end
end

Parent::Child.get_complete_namespace
#=> "Parent::Child.get_complete_namespace"
```

Some usages notes:

- `__callee__` and `__method__` will usually return the same symbol. If the method is aliased, then `__callee__` returns the method name that was invoked, while `__method__` will return the method name as it was defined.
- For a class/module method, you need to use `m.receiver`. For an instance method, you need to use `m.owner`. See [Method](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Method#owner-instance_method).

Class example:

```rb
module Parent
  class Child
    def self.get_complete_namespace
      m = method(__callee__)
      "#{m.receiver.name}.#{m.name}"
    end

    def get_complete_namespace
      m = method(__callee__)
      "#{m.owner.name}.#{m.name}"
    end

    alias_method :complete, :get_complete_namespace
  end
end

Parent::Child.get_complete_namespace
#=> "Parent::Child.get_complete_namespace"

Parent::Child.new.get_complete_namespace
#=> "Parent::Child.get_complete_namespace"

Parent::Child.new.complete
#=> "Parent::Child.complete"
```

Edit - one-liner version:

```rb
def self.get_complete_namespace
  method(__callee__).instance_eval { "#{receiver.name}.#{name}" }
end
```

Comment: For instance methods you might want to use `#` instead of `.` to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `get_complete_namespace` as follows.

```
module Grandparent
  module Parent
    module Child
      def self.get_complete_namespace
        "#{Module.nesting.first}::#{__method__}"
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

```
Grandparent::Parent::Child.get_complete_namespace
  #=> "Grandparent::Parent::Child.get_complete_namespace"
```

See [Module::nesting](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-c-nesting) and [Kernel#**method**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__).

Had the operative line of the method `Grandparent::Parent::Child::get_complete_namespace` been

```
Module.nesting
```

the method would have returned

```
[Grandparent::Parent::Child, Grandparent::Parent, Grandparent]
```

Comment: One thing that is worh mentioning that `Modul.nesting` returns an array of all opened modules (and only with `module` and `class` keywords). So if you change the first two lines into `module Gradnparent::Parent`, or the first line even to `Grandparent = Class.new do` then the method output will be affected.

Comment: Also, this method cannot be defined or inherited - `Module.nesting` does not care about `self` - if defined within the module `CompleteNamespace` and then included in another class, it will always return `[CompleteNamespace]` regardless of the namespace of class it was included in.